# Regexp Multiline

Tags: c#, regex

Help to write correct regexp for such piece of text.

Here needed :

1. To match all this strings. But the key figure is **id 123**. 
   It is necessary to cover from **set policy id 128** to **exit**
2. and how to place each of string into group, because I need each row converted into another kind of

```
set policy id 128 
from "Trust" to "Untrust" "lm pool" "172.16.2.2/32" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 128
set dst-address "MIEP"
set dst-address "MIEP WS"
set dst-address "radius1"
set dst-address "radius2"
exit
```

How can I supplement my creation:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
string patternPolicy = @"set policy (id)(.+)exit";
var matchesPolicy = Regex.Matches(
    reader.ReadToEnd(), 
    patternPolicy,
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: What's `id 123`? What is the expected output here? When you say "place each string in a group", which strings are you talking about?

Comment: There is a large text file(screenos config), where are presented such different pieces of text(a sequence of rows belonging to one custom configuration of policy). each policy differs number (id). And each single policy config ends with EXIT

Comment: you want to turn "set policy id 128" into "exit"? If so your regex is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the option `Multiline`, you need `RegexOptions.Singleline`:

```
var matchesPolicy = 
    Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), patternPolicy,RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See [Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Multiline
>   m
>   Use multiline mode, where ^ and $ match the beginning and end of each line (instead of the beginning and end of the input string). For more information, see Multiline Mode.
>
> Singleline
>   s
>   Use single-line mode, where the period (.) matches every character (instead of every character except \n). For more information, see Singleline Mode.

Then you probably need to make your quantifier lazy to avoid matching from the first `set policy (id)` to the last `exit` by adding a `?` to your quantifier:

```
string patternPolicy = @"set policy (id)(.+?)exit";
```

Another thing is, why are you putting "id" into a capturing group? **That makes no sense**.

```
string patternPolicy = @"set policy id(.+?)exit";
```

Comment: Thank yo for reply. It seem you are right! here needed SingleLine mode. And pattern is correct too. So i got groups of policy configurations. Now I need to work with each separately.each string in the policy group must be converted. please, tell have you any idea. that's what I got.in answer/

Comment: I don't understand where your next problem is. you get all matches in the resulting MatchCollection. Iterate through it and do whatever you want with the matched text.

Comment: matchesPolicy is a [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)